# Safari 13 pops up 'Glass Pane' when using Selenium sendKeys() to <input type="file"> element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

NOTE: The same thing is working as expected in Safari 12.1.2 but it's broken in Safari 13.0 & 13.1

**Issue: System pops up 'Glass Pane' when using Selenium sendKeys() method to  element.**

*Background:*
*I want to upload a file (ex. image) in my application.*

Safari 12.1.2 behaviour:
There is no need to simulate the clicking of the "Browse" button. SafariDriver automatically enters the file path onto the file-selection text box of the  element.

Safari 13 behaviour:
System pops up 'Glass Pane' when using Selenium sendKeys() method to  element.

Comment: I've also raised a ticket 'https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209780' to get it fixed by Apple Developer's. Please support and comment in the ticket, if you're experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed for this setup:

- MacOS: Catalina 10.15.4
- Safari: 13.1 (15609.1.20.111.8)
- Selenium: 3.141.59
- Scripting Language: Java 1.8